# conditionally render div based on attributes of another element vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a small container of text. What I'm trying to do is If the text length is large, collapse the div, then have a button that says "...show more", once pressed expands the div. pressed again collapses the div.

That’s fine and works.

I have an issue at the moment. The div is initially set to collapse=true. The “...show more” button is displayed.

The thing I want to change is, if the text content is not long, it will not be collapsed, the show more button will not be displayed.

**Template**

```
  <v-card v-show="showAccount" class="mb-4">
          <v-card-title class="title-container align-start">
      <div class="title-data" :class="{collapsed: isElementOverflown}" ref="title-data">
        <h1 class="title mb-2"><router-link :to="{name: 'profile', params: {account: account.account}}">{{ account.account }}</router-link></h1>
        <router-link v-if="isActiveUserAccount" :to="{name: 'account-image', params: {account: account.account}}">
          <v-avatar color="#c35219" size="56" class="mr-4 mb-2">
            <img v-if="accountMedia" :src="accountMedia" :alt="account.account" />
            <span v-else class="white--text headline">{{ account.account[0].toUpperCase() }}</span>
          </v-avatar>
        </router-link>
        <template v-else>
          <v-avatar color="#c35219" size="56" class="mr-4 mb-2">
            <img v-if="accountMedia" :src="accountMedia" :alt="account.account" />
            <span v-else class="white--text headline">{{ account.account[0].toUpperCase() }}</span>
          </v-avatar>
        </template>
        <div class="caption my-0" ref="bio">
          <nl2br v-if="account.about" tag="p" :text="account.about"></nl2br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button v-if="showButton" type="button" style="font-size:small; margin: auto; margin-right: 5%" @click="toggleHeight">
        {{showMoreTextLabel}}
        </button>
    </v-card-title>
```

**JS**

```
      mounted() {
  // elements have been created, so the `ref` will return an element.
  // but the elements have not necessarily been inserted into the DOM yet.
  // you can use $nextTick() to wait for that to have happened.
  // this is espeically necessary if you want to to get dimensions or position of that element.
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log("refs", this.$refs);  // logs correct this.$refs
    console.log("$refs.title-data", this.$refs["title-data"]); //undefined

    let el = this.$refs["title-data"];
    if (el.offsetHeight < el.scrollHeight || el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
      this.isElementOverflown = true;
      this.showButton = true;
    }
  })
},



toggleHeight() {
        if (this.$refs && 'title-data' in this.$refs) {
          this.$refs['title-data'].classList.toggle('collapsed');
          this.$refs['title-data'].classList.contains('collapsed')
                  ? this.showMoreTextLabel = "...show more"
                  : this.showMoreTextLabel = "...show less";
        }
      },
```

In `mounted` I’m getting an error that 
`this.$refs[“title-data”]` is undefined but
 `This.$refs` is there and it shows the correct refs. I’m not sure why.

Thank you for any help!

[image: intended behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed property that checks if the length of your text exceeds a given number.

```
    computed: {
             isTextLengthLongEnough() {
              if(el.offsetHeight > 150) {
              this.showButton = true;
                }
              }
```

Then you can check in your template with a `v-if` if that computed property is true or false and then display the button or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get either of the above answers to work. el was coming up as undefined, So if someone could explain to me based on the code I have in the question how to get el, that would be great.

I did a work around not ideal, but it works where I have code in `updated`, So I'm going with that for now. Thanks very much for everyone's help

Here is the code I used

```
   updated() {
      if ('title-data' in this.$refs) {
        const el = this.$refs['title-data']
        const heightDiff = Boolean(el.scrollHeight - el.offsetHeight > ALLOWED_HEIGHT_VARIANCE)
        if (heightDiff) {
          this.showButton = heightDiff
          el.className += ' read-more'
        }
      }
    },
```